# Sttp Client 3 with ZLayer type mismatch

Tags: scala, zio, sttp

I use ZLayer and Sttp Client(async to create simple http requester application but I found type mismatch error that I couldn't solve it.
Can anyone tell me why I'm getting the type mismatch error?

I use these versions of scala & libraries.

java -> 8.282.08.1-amzn

scala -> s.13.5

dev.zio -> 1.0.7

com.softwaremill.sttp.client3 -> 3.3.0

```
type mismatch;
 found   : zio.ZLayer[sttp.client3.asynchttpclient.zio.SttpClient,Nothing,ZlayerAndSttp.HttpBin]
    (which expands to)  zio.ZLayer[zio.Has[sttp.client3.SttpBackend[zio.Task,sttp.capabilities.zio.ZioStreams with sttp.capabilities.WebSockets]],Nothing,zio.Has[ZlayerAndSttp.HttpBin.Service]]
 required: zio.ZLayer[ZlayerAndSttp.HttpBin,?,?]
    (which expands to)  zio.ZLayer[zio.Has[ZlayerAndSttp.HttpBin.Service],?,?]
    program.provideCustomLayer((AsyncHttpClientZioBackend.layer() >>> HttpBin.live) >>> HttpBin.live)
```

Here's the whole code

```scala
import zio._
import sttp.client3._
import sttp.client3.circe._
import sttp.client3.asynchttpclient.zio._
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import zio.console.Console


object ZlayerAndSttp extends App {

  case class HttpBinResponse(origin: String, headers: Map[String, String])

  type HttpBin = Has[HttpBin.Service]
  object HttpBin {
    trait Service {
      def sendRequest: ZIO[HttpBin with SttpClient, Throwable, HttpBinResponse]
    }

    val live: ZLayer[SttpClient, Nothing, HttpBin] = ZLayer.succeed(new Service {
      override def sendRequest: ZIO[HttpBin with SttpClient, Throwable, HttpBinResponse] = {
        val request = basicRequest
          .get(uri"https://httpbin.org/get")
          .response(asJson[HttpBinResponse])
        sendR(request).map(_.body).absolve.map(res => HttpBinResponse(res.origin, res.headers))
      }
    })

    def sendRequest: ZIO[HttpBin with SttpClient, Throwable, HttpBinResponse] = ZIO.accessM(_.get.sendRequest)
  }

  val request = basicRequest
    .get(uri"https://httpbin.org/get")
    .response(asJson[HttpBinResponse])

  override def run(args: List[String]): URIO[zio.ZEnv, ExitCode] = {
    val program = for {
      result <- HttpBin.sendRequest
      _ <- console.putStrLn(s"${result.origin}, ${result.headers}")
    } yield ()
    program.provideCustomLayer((AsyncHttpClientZioBackend.layer() >>> HttpBin.live) >>> HttpBin.live) // type mismatch
      .exitCode

    // ↓these lines of code run with no errors but I can't understand why
//    val program: ZIO[Console with SttpClient, Throwable, Unit] = for {
//      response <- send(request)
//      _ <- console.putStrLn(s"${response.body.toString}")
//    } yield ()
//    program.provideCustomLayer(AsyncHttpClientZioBackend.layer()).exitCode
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be making your life a bit more complicated than needed.

What the end code looks like depends on what you want to achieve here. If you are trying to hide the use of `Sttp` behind the `HttpBin` interface, then your layer definition should instead look like:

```
    val live: ZLayer[SttpClient, Nothing, HttpBin] = 
      (for {
        client <- ZIO.environment[SttpClient]
      } yield new Service {
          override def sendRequest: ZIO[Any, Throwable, HttpBinResponse] = {
            val request = basicRequest
              .get(uri"https://httpbin.org/get")
              .response(asJson[HttpBinResponse])

            sendR(request)
              .map(_.body)
              .absolve
              .map(res => HttpBinResponse(res.origin, res.headers))
              .provide(client)
  }
      }).toLayer
```

Then your accessor method becomes:

```
def sendRequest: ZIO[HttpBin, Throwable, HttpBinResponse] = 
  ZIO.accessM(_.get.sendRequest)
```

And you can use it with:

```
  override def run(args: List[String]): URIO[zio.ZEnv, ExitCode] = {
    val program = for {
      result <- HttpBin.sendRequest
      _ <- console.putStrLn(s"${result.origin}, ${result.headers}")
    } yield ()

    program
      .provideCustomLayer(AsyncHttpClientZioBackend.layer() >>> HttpBin.live)
      .exitCode
```

The thing to note here is that with layer composition I am using just the vertical operator because `HttpBin.live` depends on a layer with `SttpClient` but we are "hiding" that fact from the calling method so you could create a `test` variant of `HttpBin` that didn't require Sttp if needed.

If you don't need the information hiding you can instead remove the intermediate layer altogether and just treat your `sendRequest` as a stand alone method.

```
object HttpBin {
  def sendRequest: ZIO[SttpClient, Throwable, HttpBinResponse] = {
     val request = basicRequest
       .get(uri"https://httpbin.org/get")
       .response(asJson[HttpBinResponse])

     sendR(request)
       .map(_.body)
       .absolve
       .map(res => HttpBinResponse(res.origin, res.headers))
}
```

Then you can just call this method and all you need to do is provide the `SttpClient` layer.